# Why is WPO(whole-program optimization) not doing any improvements in my program size? (FPC 2.4.0)

Tags: optimization, size, compilation, freepascal, fpc

I use FPC 2.4.0 for WinXP(binary from the official page), also tryed with same version but compiled from source on my comp.
I put something like this:

`I:\pascal\fpc-2.4.0.source\fpc-2.4.0\compiler\ppc386 -FWserver-1.wpo -OWsymbolliveness -CX -XX -Xs- -al -Os -oServer1.o Server

I:\pascal\fpc-2.4.0.source\fpc-2.4.0\compiler\ppc386 -FWserver-2.wpo -OWsymbolliveness -Fwserver-1.wpo -Owsymbolliveness -CX -XX -Xs- -al -Os -oServer2.o Server

..(up to 100 times)`

but always same .wpo files, and same .o sizes(.s, assembly files change intermittently)

I also not(through compiler messages), that not used variables are still alive.
Also tryed -OWall -owall
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make the second one -Fw and -Ow  (lowercase second letter) as in the documentation for WPO

http://wiki.freepascal.org/Whole_Program_Optimization

Comment: Why can't I do this optimization on Windows?